# I've tried to make a program, but console still shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" and I don't know what's wrong

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The program is supposed to work like this:

First it gets SENTENCE (string) and MUTATION factor (double) from the user. Then it changes string SENTENCE into chars array (ARRAY 1). After that it makes 5 new char arrays which length is equal to ARRAY 1's length. Each one of them is filled with random chars (only letters and space). Then program choose one of those 5 which is the most similar to ARRAY 1. The winner "multiplies" into next 5 arrays. In each of them, the program verifies compliance with an ARRAY 1. If the char suits the one from ARRAY 1, then program doesn't change it. If the char doesn't suit the one from ARRAY 1, then it mutates or not (according to MUTATION factor and random probability). Then program choose an array that's most similar to ARRAY 1, the winner "mulitplies" etc. Program works untill the array that program's made is identical to ARRAY 1. 'Counter' (static int) counts number of "generations" of arrays that have passed before program made proper array.

I suspect that someting may be wrong with the last method. But I really don't know what is it. Here's the code I wrote:

```
static int counter;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner skaner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence = skaner.nextLine();
    double mutation = Double.parseDouble(skaner.nextLine());

//
        ArrayList<char[]> candidates = Draw(ChangeIntoChars(sentence), mutation);
        char[] candidate = ChooseTheBestOne(candidates,
                ChangeIntoChar(sentence));
        String result = CheckAndDraw(candidate, ChangeIntoChars(sentence),
                mutation);
        System.out.print(result);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(counter);
}

    public static char[] ChangeIntoChars (String sentence) {

        char[] chars = sentence.toCharArray();
        return chars;
    }



    public static ArrayList<char[]> Draw (char [] chars, double mutation) {

        char [] random1 = new char [chars.length];
        char [] random2 = new char [chars.length];
        char [] random3 = new char [chars.length];
        char [] random4 = new char [chars.length];
        char [] random5 = new char [chars.length];

        Random r = new Random();


        for (int i=0; i<random1.length; i++) {
            if          (random1[i]==chars[i]) {}
            else        {double p = Math.random();
                        if (mutation>p){
                String alphabet = "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuwxyzżź ";
                random1[i]=(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
                        }
                        else {}
                        }}

        for (int i=0; i<random2.length; i++) {
            if      (random2[i]==chars[i]) {}
            else        {double p = Math.random();
                        if (mutation>p){
                String alphabet = "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuwxyzżź ";
                random2[i]=(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
                        }
                        else {}
                        }}

        for (int i=0; i<random3.length; i++) {
            if      (random3[i]==chars[i]) {}
            else        {double p = Math.random();
                        if (mutation>p){
                String alphabet = "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuwxyzżź ";
                random3[i]=(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
                        }
                        else {}
                        }}

        for (int i=0; i<random4.length; i++) {
            if      (random4[i]==chars[i]) {}
            else        {double p = Math.random();
                        if (mutation>p){
                String alphabet = "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuwxyzżź ";
                random4[i]=(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
                        }
                        else {}
                        }}

        for (int i=0; i<random5.length; i++) {
            if      (random5[i]==chars[i]) {}
            else        {double p = Math.random();
                        if (mutation>p){
                String alphabet = "aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuwxyzżź ";
                random5[i]=(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
                        }
                        else {}
                        }}


        ArrayList<char[]> candidates = new ArrayList<char[]>();
        candidates.add(random1);
        candidates.add(random2);
        candidates.add(random3);
        candidates.add(random4);
        candidates.add(random5);

        return candidates;
    }
    public static char [] ChooseTheBestOne(ArrayList<char[]>candidates,char[]chars) {

        char [] number1 = candidates.get(0);
        char [] number2 = candidates.get(1);
        char [] number3 = candidates.get(2);
        char [] number4 = candidates.get(3);
        char [] number5 = candidates.get(4);

        int j = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<number1.length; i++){
            if (number1[i]==chars[i]){
                j++;}
            }

        int k = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<number2.length; i++){
            if (number2[i]==chars[i]){
                k++;}
            }

        int l = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<number3.length; i++){
            if (number3[i]==chars[i]){
                l++;}
            }

        int m = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<number4.length; i++){
            if (number4[i]==chars[i]){
                m++;}
            }

        int n = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<number5.length; i++){
            if (number5[i]==chars[i]){
                n++;}
            }

        int [] whosTheWinner = {j,k,l,m,n};
        int max = 0;
        char[] winner = null;
        for (int x=0; x<whosTheWinner.length; x++) {
            if (whosTheWinner[x]> max) {max = whosTheWinner[x];
                if  (x==0) {winner = number1;}
                else if (x==1) {winner = number2;}
                else if (x==2) {winner = number3;}
                else if (x==3) {winner = number4;}
                else if (x==4) {winner = number5;}

        }}
        counter++;
        return winner ;
        }
    public static String CheckAndDraw (char[]winner,char[]chars,double mutation){
        int i = 0;
        String end = "This is not what I meant.";

        boolean success;


        if (winner[i]==chars[i]){
            success = true;
            end = "END";
        }
        else {success = false;}


        while (success!=true){

            ArrayList<char[]> resultsOfTheDraw = Draw(winner, mutation);
            winner = ChooseTheBestOne(resultsOfTheDraw, chars);

            }



        return end;

        }
    }
```

Comment: mark the line it says that throws the exception

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where the error occurs.  What does it say?

Comment: A nullpointer exception is the signal that one of your variables is nog initialized. It will signal on which line that is so you can determine which variable it is.

Comment: Also, your code is unreadable, because it's incorrectly indented. Find the keyboard shortcut allowing to format code in your IDE, and use it.

Comment: Error occurs on line "if (winner[i]==chars[i])"

Comment: So, either winner is null, or chars is null. Use your debugger, or add a trace in the code to find which one is null, and then analyze your code to understand why it is.

Comment: Your code has a lot of faults in fact ... What is the class name BTW ??

Comment: Use try catch where you are getting the **NullPointerException**.Put the error line in try and print the parameters in catch.

Comment: At the risk of sounding overly harsh, genetic algorithms are probably best tackled after having a solid foundation of debugging skills.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, in the method `ChooseTheBestOne()`, in the if-else ladder at the end of the method, sometimes none of the conditions are true and thus `winner` remains null. You need to put an `else` clause in that ladder that assigns something to `winner`.